# UIView animation inside UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uianimation

I have an animation that runs for several seconds in response to a tap gesture.  While the animation is running, the UITapGestureRecognizer won't respond to additional taps.  Once the animation completes, the recognizer works again.

I've tried running the animation inside

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), etc.
```

but additional taps are still blocked.  If I try running the animation inside

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), etc.
```

then the animation doesn't show at all.  I vaguely remember reading somewhere that animations have to be run on the main thread.

Any suggestions for running an animation that doesn't block subsequent gestures?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using UIView animation blocks, you can use `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` with the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` option.

Also, you're correct that animations must be performed on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.  I was using the more basic animateWithDuration: method.